# My candle is growing living crystals

Tags: everyday-life, amorphous-solids

My candle had no wick left, so I put the jar on a coffee warmer to melt the wax and release the scent. It worked great, the house smelled good. Then I forgot about it. 2 days went by and I just happened to glance at it and this is what I saw: it looks like crystals growing. Not hard like mineral crystals but alive and moving, growing up the sides of the jar to the top. What's up with that?

Comment: I have pics and video

Comment: The heat evaporates wax, which condenses on colder surfaces. It will preferentially condense where some sufficiently cool surface is close to the largest density of wax vapour, which tends to produce branching (dendritic patterns). This is called diffusion limited aggregation.

Comment: @AndersSandberg Please post that answer as an answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: Adding a picture or two would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The heat evaporates wax, which condenses on colder surfaces. It will preferentially condense where some sufficiently cool surface is close to the largest density of wax vapour, which tends to produce branching (dendritic patterns). This is called [diffusion limited aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion-limited_aggregation).